# How to send String value to SearchView in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-layout, android-studio

I am having a bit of a problem with my code. I have a SearchView which allows the user to search the entered value from a SQL database using PHP and JSON in order to view the results in to a RecyclerView. In basic, i am using Volley to connect my Android application to a webserver.

The Problem here is that i have a button on my search layout which when pressed, pops a calendar asking the user to select a date. When the user selects a date, the selected date is then displayed in to a TextView. However, i want the Date to be displayed in the SearchView.

Here is my code for the search class:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFish;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;


    private TextView tvDisplayDate;
    //private DatePicker dpResult;
    private Button btnChangeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    SearchView searchView = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // adds item to action bar
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, menu);

        // Get Search item from action bar and Get Search service
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) 
    MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {


searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconified(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Every time when you press search button on keypad an Activity is 
    recreated which in turn calls this function
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Get search query and create object of class AsyncFetch
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            if (searchView != null) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
            }
            new AsyncFetch(query).execute();

        }
    }

    // Create class AsyncFetch
    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;
        String searchQuery;

        public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery){
            this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                url = new URL("http://192.168.x.x/test/test-search.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data 
    from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve 
    data
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // add parameter to our above url
                Uri.Builder builder = new 
    Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
    OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {
                    return("Connection error");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            if(result.equals("no rows")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Results found for 
    entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{

                try {

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as 
    class objects
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                        fishData.datecodes = 
    json_data.getString("datecode");
                        fishData.names = json_data.getString("name");
                        fishData.emails = json_data.getString("email");
                        fishData.timecodes = json_data.getInt("timecode");
                        fishData.numbers = json_data.getInt("numbers");
                        data.add(fishData);
                    }

                    // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                    mRVFish = (RecyclerView) 
    findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                    mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
                    mRVFish.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mRVFish.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // You to understand what actually error is and handle 
    it appropriately
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }

    }




    // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, null);

        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        //dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1, if you want to
                .append(year).append("")
                .append(month<10?("0"+month):(month)).append("")
                .append(day<10?("0"+day):(day)).append(""));

        // set current date into datepicker
        //dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener,
                        year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new 
    StringBuilder().append(year).append("")
                    .append(month<10?("0"+month):(month)).append("")
                    .append(day<10?("0"+day):(day)).append(""));

            // set selected date into datepicker also
            //dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

        }
    };
}
```

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fishPriceList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_login"
        android:text="Change Date"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for view container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFishName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textFishName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#666" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimeCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Time Code"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textType"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#666" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the search_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".SearchResultsActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Also i cant seem to "Order-by" the search results. The search is fine and it works as intended. But the issue is, i cant order-by the result set in the RecyclerView.

Comment: `"However, i want the Date to be displayed in the SearchView."`, so what is unclear after reading `SearchView` javadocs?

Comment: On my code, i tried to change `tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);` TO `tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SearchView);` In here "SearchView" is the ID of my SearchView. It gives an error saying textView only allowed. Also Tried to add `private SearchView;` but didnt help

Comment: Can you at least suggest someway to achieve this?

Comment: you already have `searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

Comment: I dont think you understood the question. Sorry that would be on me. There is no issue with the search result what so ever. the only issue here is, there is a button in my layout which shows up a calendar when clicked. and after i choose a date, that date is displayed on a textview. instead of displaying it on textview, i want it to be displayed in my searchView. There is a separate textview under the button to display the date. i want that textview gone and date to be displayed on to the searchView once i select the date from the calendar

Comment: ok so you posted two xml layouts, there is no extra SearchView on them, so what SearchView are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry. The question is now edited. There is the search view layout. "action_search" is the ID. I want my dates to go to that searchView.

Comment: so it is part of your action bar menu, then you are getting it as i said by: `searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, once you have the reference to your `SearchView` use it to set the query text on it

Comment: sorry if this seems a bit annoying but i still don't get how i could display the dates on SearchView. `<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_login"
        android:text="Change Date"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />` That displays the button to change date. That button shows calendar. But the value goes to a TextView. How to send that date value to SearchView?

Comment: As far as i know `tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);` that is where the date is now displayed. I want that date to be displayed on SearchView

Comment: read `SearchView` documentation to find out how to set the query string, did you read it? whats unclear with setting the query string?